# 2008 Honda Lead SCV 100 Running Issues

Tags: honda, scooter

my gf has recently been having problems with her scooter, in that it stopped working, almost as if there was no fuel or spark. I drained the fuel, tested the diaphragm operation, put in fresh fuel, changed the spark plug, checked all the air filters, inspected and cleaned the carby, and ensured all lines were in their proper position so as not to crush any lines when reassembling. Now it seems a whole lot better, BUT, when the scooter is on its stand, any weight applied to the frame (seat on or off) makes the scooter conk out. Off the stand it seems fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Does it just ***BOOM*** die, or does it sputter itself into non-compliance?

Comment: It is a slight sputter but it happens very quickly. With enough weight it is just BOOM die

Comment: Any one have any further input?

Comment: split hose and/or faulty auto choke

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue has been found. Yesterday I noticed some wires in sheathing (marked 179) that were touching the exhaust pipe. I moved them as a precaution and afterward (I didn't make the connection *slight pun* at the time), the scooter worked. Went back to same issue that evening. Moved it today, noticed when on stand it came in contact with the pipe, and when off stand it pulled away from pipe. Moved it and secured it, hey presto ;) Must have been a temp sensor cable or something of the sorts.